# Configure local nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: macos, nginx

I'm running a nginx on my local machine (macOS) and I want to use it as a reverse proxy. Calling `my.local` should serve me `http://192.168.178.60:8000`.

But it looks like as there is a syntax error in my config file. Is it wrong to use two `server` blocks? If I remove the second one, I can call `localhost:8080` and see the default output. If I add the custom server block, I cannot call `localhost:8080`.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       my.local:80;
        server_name  my.local;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.178.60:8000;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: You are not obligated to use a hostname with the `listen` directive, however if you do it, the hostname should be resolvable as one of your local interface(s) IP addresses at the nginx startup time. What `nginx -t` command says about your configuration?

Comment: @IvanShatsky `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 192.168.178.60:80 failed (49: Can't assign requested address)`

Comment: To bind on a privileged port (<=1023) you need to run nginx as root.